HTTP error: BadStatusLine: [] for Python REST API request (Sonoff DIY Mode Light Bulb)
I cannot for the life of me figure out why my Pico W and Micropython will not work with this Sonoff bulb.
IP of the bulb is correct, URL is correct and works when I run the request in Chrome through an API tester extension.
But for some reason any GET and POST requests to the URL on the Pi Pico W are met with HTTP error: BadStatusLine: []. I am using Thonny by the way.
I've tried the following:

Setting a "timeout" in the request (timeout = 5) but that only throws
another error, enomem
Using requests AND urequests with the same
result

import network
import socket
import time
import requests
import urequests
from time import sleep
from machine import Pin
 
led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect("NETGEAR93","...")
    
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print("Waiting to connect...\n")
        sleep(1)
    
    print(wlan.ifconfig())
    '''
        192.168.0.54
    '''
    url = 'http://192.168.0.54:8081/zeroconf/switch'
    myobj = {'data':{'switch':'off'} }

    x = urequests.post(url, json = myobj, headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' })
    x.close()
try:
    connect()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    machine.reset()

